# Drill down into iframe

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I have this big messy thing that drills down into a iframe to retrieve an attribute from an XML result. (I'm doing it this way to avoid a billion other problems involved with getting data out of this offsite server.)

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect(//ALL THE CONNECTS!);
    mysqli_select_db(//THE_DB, $link);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM jos_mls AS mls
                INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON mls.MSTLISTBRD = active.AGENTUID
                LIMIT 10;";

    $result = mysqli_query($query);

    $array = array(); 
    $index = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $array[$index] = $row;
        $index++;
    }

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $mls = $value[1];
        $street = $value[5].' '.$value[6];
        $city = $value[9];
        $state = $value[10];
        $zip = $value[11];
        $url = "http://eligibility.sc.egov.usda.gov/eligibility/eligibilityservice?eligibilityType=Property&requestString=<?xml version='1.0'?><Eligibility xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='/var/lib/tomcat5/webapps/eligibility/Eligibilitywsdl.xsd'><PropertyRequest StreetAddress1='".$street."' StreetAddress2='' StreetAddress3='' City='".$city."' State='".$state."' County='' Zip='".$zip."' Program='RBS'></PropertyRequest></Eligibility>";
        $frame = '<iframe class="frame" mls="'.$mls.'" style="width: 10px; height: 10px;" src="'.$url.'"></iframe>';
        echo $frame;
    }

    mysql_close($link);
?>
<div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.frame').each(function(){
            var mls = $(this).attr('mls'),
                usda = $(this).contents().find('Property').attr('Eligibility');
            $('#test').append(mls+' '+usda+'<br/>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The data in the iframes looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Eligibility xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Adjusted AnnualIncome="" TotalDeduction="" AdjustedIncome="" ElderlyDeduction="" YoungDeduction="">
        </Adjusted>
        <Section502Guaranted MaximumAdjusted="" Eligible="">
        </Section502Guaranted>
        <Section502Direct MaximumAdjusted="" Eligible="">
        </Section502Direct>
        <Property Eligibility="InEligible" MapURL="http://rdgdwe.sc.egov.usda.gov/eligibilitymaps/index.jsp?app=RBSIELG&amp;ADDRESS=7865 ILLINOIS CASEYVILLE&amp;STATE=IL&amp;ZIP=62232" />
        <ErrorResponse EngineId="" HostName="" MaxSeverity="" LogFile="" Class="" Module="" Severity="" Time="">
                <Message Code="" Type="" Text="" />
        </ErrorResponse>
</Eligibility>
```

I need the `Eligibility` attribute from the `Property` node...
**UPDATE** Sorry, hit send prematurely.  The result I get now for `$(this).contents().find('Property').attr('Eligibility')` is just "undefined".

Comment: Avoid using iframes, most of the iframe elements are deprecated.

Comment: @Jonast92 You want to elaborate on that? Deprecated iframe elements? Iframes are very much alive and kicking and will be for a long time.

Comment: W3Schools about iframes: align : Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01, frameborder : Not supported in HTML5., longdesc : Not supported in HTML5., marginheight : Not supported in HTML5., marginwidth : Not supported in HTML5., scrolling : Not supported in HTML5. PLUS tips that I hace received over the last years from guys who have been in the field for a long time and basically say that it's outdated, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: What do you have to say about that @Rudie ?

Comment: About w3schools? [Just this.](http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to access the iframe the correct way with JS and use the XML DOM:

```
var f = $('.frame')[0];
var Property = f.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('Property')[0];
var Eligibility = Property.getAttribute('Eligibility');
```

Or something like that. Beware: this is only possible if domains, ports and protocols match! (Of the owner document and iframe document.)

**EDIT** Ah, I see now the iframe's URL will most likely be different than your website's. Than this won't work. Javascript (the browser) won't allow cross-site scripting. For very good security reasons.

You'll need to read the XML with PHP. Much easier too:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); // requires allow_url_fopen to be on
$Eligibility = (string)$xml->Property['Eligibility'];
```

(Didn't test that one.)

Comment: The iframe URL domain will always be different than my current domain. So you're saying the content of the iframe has to be on the same server as the js script that's trying to access it? I tried using cURL, but it was such a pain and wouldn't do what I wanted it to.  How would you read the iframe XML with PHP?

Comment: It doesn't do anything.  I tried just `print_r` or `echo` on `$xml` and `$Eligibility` and nothing shows up. allow_url_fopen is set to on as you mentioned.

Comment: That URL isn't to an actual file, it's a return from that URL.  Does that need to be treated any differently?

Comment: `print_r($xml)` doesn't show anything?? That's weird. It should show **some** 'XML' or throw a notice or warning somewhere. Try `var_dump($xml)`.

Comment: if `$url` is a valid URL, PHP will download the document automatically and simplexml will parse it. The "PHP will download the document automatically" part requires  `allow_url_fopen`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26579/discussion-between-rudie-and-tplummer)